# How to build a case sensitive query for MySQL

Tags: sequelize.js

As per title. I have found some questions roughly regarding the topic, but either proposed solutions do not work for me (error is thrown or generated query is missing conditions) or are clearly wrong, eg. suggesting that `$eq` operator is case sensitive - it is definitely not.

How do I modify this query to make it case sensitive?

```
models.Item.findOne({
    where: {
       name: 'soughtString' 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to combine `eq` with `SHA1` function like this:

```js
models.Item.findOne({
    where: {
     [Op.and]: [{
         name: 'soughtString',
       },
       sequelize.where(
         sequelize.fn('SHA1', sequelize.col('name')),
         '=', 
         sequelize.fn('SHA1', 'soughtString')
       )
    ]
});
```

This should be like a SQL condition like this:

```sql
where name = 'soughtString' and SHA1(name)= SHA1('soughtString')
```

Comment: Would you have a suggestion how to achieve the case sensitive search but with `LIKE` instead of `=`? I tried changing the comparator to `LIKE` with a few combinations of the `sequelize.where()` inputs, but it doesn't work. Doesn't throw errors but query returns no results.

Comment: I don;t think so. Maybe this can be achieved with something like a function to search a substring but I'm not sure